# Selecting the median of three date variables

Tags: r, date, median

I am trying to select the median date from three variables in R. For another piece of code, I used `pmin` (see below). I am wondering if anyone knows of a comparable function to select the median date. `hadmin1`, `hadmin2` and `hadmin3` are in date time format. Thanks!

```
covidtest2 <- covidtest %>%
  mutate(
    hadmin1new = case_when(
      probid == 1 & thirdhosp == 1 ~ pmin(hadmin1, hadmin2, hadmin3),
      probid == 1 &
        thirdhosp == 0 ~ pmin(hadmin1, hadmin2),
      probid == 0 ~ hadmin1
    )
  ) %>%
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can do: (I made up my own data, since you didn't supply any)

```
set.seed(42)
datetimes <- as.POSIXct(runif(18, max = 1e9), origin = '1970-01-01', tz = 'GMT')
df <- data.frame(dt1 = datetimes[1:6], dt2 = datetimes[7:12], dt3 = datetimes[13:18])

df$new <- mapply(\(x, y, z) median(c(x, y, z)), df$dt1, df$dt2, df$dt3) |> 
  as.POSIXct(origin = '1970-01-01', tz = 'GMT')
df
                  dt1                 dt2                 dt3
1 1998-12-28 00:47:23 1993-05-05 07:51:54 1999-08-14 23:10:47
2 1999-09-11 18:43:33 1974-04-08 15:23:17 1978-02-04 08:27:04
3 1979-01-25 19:12:14 1990-10-27 01:51:30 1984-08-25 14:40:22
4 1996-04-25 15:53:46 1992-05-05 11:19:44 1999-10-15 19:08:42
5 1990-05-03 14:38:38 1984-07-03 22:29:36 2000-12-31 01:33:48
6 1986-06-14 01:19:09 1992-10-15 01:24:11 1973-09-21 19:22:41
                  new
1 1998-12-28 00:47:23
2 1978-02-04 08:27:04
3 1984-08-25 14:40:22
4 1996-04-25 15:53:46
5 1990-05-03 14:38:38
6 1986-06-14 01:19:09
```